# PHP: Show first word for last name

Tags: php

I wish to make something that cuts the name to e.g:

> Alex Andersson

to uppercase first word after space(first name) "A" like this:

> Alex A.

Right now it displays the full name like this:

```
echo $data["full_name"];
```

Hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You described it vaguely, but as I understand that, you can do something like:

```
$names = explode(" ", $data["full_name"]);
foreach ($names as $key => $name)
{
  if ($key == 0)
    continue;
  $names[$key] = substr($name, 0, 1).'.';
} 
echo implode(" ", $names);
```

This shortens every name except first one.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store the first name and last name in different variables, as you can never tell at what position the second name would be.

You can access the first letter of a variable using square brackets.

```
$data[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

For only two names

```
preg_replace('/^([A-Z][a-z]+)\s([A-Z])([a-z]+)$/', "\$1 \$2.", $data["full_name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list($fname, $sname) = explode(' ', $data["full_name"]);
$sname = strtoupper(substr($sname, 0, 1));
$new_name = $fname . $sname . '.';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$nameParts = explode(' ', $data['full_name']);
$lastName = substr(array_pop($nameParts), 0, 1) . '.';
$firstNames = implode(' ', $nameParts);

echo $firstNames . ' ' . $lastName;
```

Comment: I receive 
Warning: substr() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in  at the lin $lastName

Comment: Sorry, mixed up the parameters, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
shortened = substr($data["full_name"], 0, strpos($data["full_name"], " ") + 1) + ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clear:

```
list($forename, $surname) = explode(' ', $data['full_name']);
echo $forename . ' ' . $surname[0] . '.';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "Alex Andersson";
$name_arr =  explode(" ", $name);
echo ucfirst($name_arr[0])." ".strtoupper($name_arr[1][0]);
```